# Toolbar перекрывает часть Fragmenta

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой. Создаю приложение на основе Navigation Drawer Activity. При выборе пункта из всплывающего слева меню (NavigationView), контейнер отображается под ToolBar-ом. Заранее благодарю за помощь)[image: Скриншот]

activity_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    tools:context="com.example.march.exider.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java-код
StartActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.MenuItem;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){

            case R.id.test:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
                break;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        // Выделяем выбранный пункт меню в шторке
        item.setChecked(true);
        // Выводим выбранный пункт в заголовке
        setTitle(item.getTitle());

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Класс Fragmenta, где отображается recycleView

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

        private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;

        private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            // используем linear layout manager
            final LinearLayoutManager  mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            //наполнение массива
            list = getData();

            // создаем адаптер
            mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            return view;
        }

        private ArrayList<String> getData() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                list.add(i, "item " + i);
            }
            return list;
        }

    }
```

Класс-адаптер заполнения

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

    // класс view holder-а с помощью которого мы получаем ссылку на каждый элемент
    // отдельного пункта списка
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageView mImageView;
        // ссылки на элементы в разметке карточки
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
            mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ig_recycler_item);
        }
    }
    // Конструктор
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataset) {
        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    // Создает новые views (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        // тут можно программно менять атрибуты лэйаута (size, margins, paddings и др.)
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Заменяет контент отдельного view (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));

    }
    // Возвращает размер данных (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить к `RecyclerView` `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: Воспользовался вашим советом, но, к сожалению , не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение, воспользовавшись подсказкой ahgpoug, только вставил в другое место. Добавил строку app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" 
в разметку content_main.xml в корневой элемент

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"> !!Данная строка

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```